# check_nrpe nagios3 gives status unknown

Tags: nagios

I'm trying to excute the following command:

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugings/check_nrpe -H xxxxxxx -c check_disk -a 60 80 /dev/sda1
```

but I got the following message:

> CHECK_NRPE: Received 0 bytes from daemon.  Check the remote server logs for error messages.

When I consult the log in the remote host, I found that:

> anonymous rsyslogd-2359: action 'action 17' resumed (module 'builtin:ompipe') [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]

The command `/usr/lib/nagios/plugings/check_disk -a 60 80 /dev/sda1` is working fine in the remote host.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to check:

On the machine where you have NRPE installed, check the `nrpe.cfg` file. Make sure the `allowed_hosts=` line is uncommented and that its value includes the IP address of the Nagios server that's trying to connect to it.  Make sure the `dont_blame_nrpe` line is uncommented and it's value is set to `1`, i.e.: `dont_blame_nrpe=1`.

Restart nrpe.

If you have firewall rules enabled on this machine, make sure there's a rule to allow connections to tcp port 5666.

Comment: thank you for your reply, i have that already but the same problem is persistent and when i use the following command : /user/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H address_ip -c check_disk -a -w 60 -c 80 -p /dev/sda2 i got the line : Incorrect command line arguments supplied

Comment: On the monitored host, edit the `check_disk` command definition found in `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg` to accept arguments ARG1, ARG2, and ARG3. `command[check_disk]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -p $ARG3$` Restart the nrpe service. On the nagios server, try the command `/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H address_ip -c check_disk -a 60 80 /dev/sda2` Double check all of these paths modify as necessary to match the correct paths for your installation.